# compiled pdfs cannot be opened in Adobe Reader 11

Tags: miktex, texniccenter, viewers

I use TeXnic-Center 2.0 Beta 2 (64 Bit) and MiKTeX 2.9.
I have a problem with my Adobe Reader 11. I cannot open compiled pdfs, AR 11 says that the pdf is damaged and cannot be repaired. I already changed the server in the "Viewer"-Tab from "acroviewR11" to "AcroViewR11" but it still does not work. I also re-installed AR, but this problem remains.

Do you know what can cause this problem or does anybody have same problems and knows a solution?
If you need further specific information, just ask me.

Comment: Have you tried your PDF with any other viewer (Foxit Reader, Sumatra PDF, ...) or another version of AR?

Comment: hi no I didn't try an other viewer because the compiled pdf's have to be opened by AR therefore it is important that it works with this program.

Comment: It is still helpful if you try and open it in another viewer and report back; this can tell us if it problem is related in AR or not.

Comment: I experienced regularly (and saw it on other people's systems too), that TeXnic-Center would somehow "get stuck" in a mode where it will keep Acrobat Reader from accessing the file correctly. The only solution to get things back running was closing TeXniC as well as Reader, delete the .pdf, and restart TeXniC.

Comment: I already tried to open the pdfs with AR IX, but it does not work either

Comment: A different viewer; not just a different version of the same viewer! (Try one of the ones Daniel has suggested.) Furthermore, a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be nice.

Comment: Have you checked the executable path?  Is it something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe` ?

Comment: @ daniel: yes, i already did and i also adpated the setting you suggested and tried Foxit Reader, but still does not work; so it should be something wrong with the compiling process in the Texniccenter.Do you maybe know what it could be?

Comment: @bingbong: Not out of my crystal ball. (1) I guess you have already tried different documents, including a minimal one? (2) Have you tried compiling with some other front end than TexnicCenter? Side note: I got your last message only by accident today – there must not be a space between the '@' and the name you want to address.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I have these settings and everything works just fine for me.  You should also try deleting all the auxiliary files (and .pdf) to see if it works.

[image]

Especially the Server settings ('acroviewR11') may solve your problems.